# Azure ARM dependencies between nested templates

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager

I've created a template that has two nested templates. The first nested template defines an SQL server as:

```
{
  "name": "[variables('sqlServerName')]",
  "type": "Microsoft.Sql/servers",
  "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
  "apiVersion": "2014-04-01-preview",
  "dependsOn": [],
  "tags": {
    "displayName": "SqlServer"
  },
  "properties": {
    "administratorLogin": "[parameters('sqlAdministratorLogin')]",
    "administratorLoginPassword": "[parameters('adminLoginPassword')]"
  },
  "resources": [
    {
      "name": "AllowAllWindowsAzureIps",
      "type": "firewallrules",
      "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
      "apiVersion": "2014-04-01-preview",
      "dependsOn": [
        "[resourceId('Microsoft.Sql/servers', variables('sqlServerName'))]"
      ],
      "properties": {
        "startIpAddress": "0.0.0.0",
        "endIpAddress": "0.0.0.0"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

and the second nested template defines a database that will be hosted on the above server:

```
{
  "name": "[concat(parameters('sqlServerName'), '/', 'Admin')]",
  "type": "Microsoft.Sql/servers/databases",
  "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
  "apiVersion": "2014-04-01-preview",
  "dependsOn": [],
  "tags": {
    "displayName": "AdminApiDb"
  },
  "properties": {
    "collation": "[parameters('AdminApiDbCollation')]",
    "edition": "[parameters('AdminApiDbEdition')]",
    "maxSizeBytes": "1073741824",
    "requestedServiceObjectiveName": "[parameters('AdminApiDbRequestedServiceObjectiveName')]"
  }
}
```

And then my parent template looks like:

```
 {
  "name": "Shared",
  "type": "Microsoft.Resources/deployments",
  "apiVersion": "2016-09-01",
  "dependsOn": [],
  "properties": {
    "mode": "Incremental",
    "templateLink": {
      "uri": "[concat(parameters('_artifactsLocation'), '/', variables('SharedTemplateFolder'), '/', variables('SharedTemplateFileName'), parameters('_artifactsLocationSasToken'))]",
      "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0"
    }
},
{
  "name": "Admin",
  "type": "Microsoft.Resources/deployments",
  "apiVersion": "2016-09-01",
  "dependsOn": [
    "[concat('Microsoft.Resources/deployments/', 'Shared')]"
  ],
  "properties": {
    "mode": "Incremental",
    "templateLink": {
      "uri": "[concat(parameters('_artifactsLocation'), '/', variables('AdminTemplateFolder'), '/', variables('AdminTemplateFileName'), parameters('_artifactsLocationSasToken'))]",
      "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0"
    }
}
```

But when trying to deploy this it errors with:

> The resource 'Microsoft.Sql/servers/mysqlserver' is not defined in the template.

How can I get it to the database to see the sql server in the sibling template? It does deploy the sql server with the correct name, so it's not a naming issue.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is absolutely no sense in creating nested templates for those resources, but if you want to do it that way, you should define the actual nested template invocation to depend on one another (so second nested template should depend on the first one) in the **parent** template, not the resource **inside** the nested templates.

You can only use `dependsOn` for resources in the template, and those resources are not in the template.

ok, your template contains another bug, you cannot use reference function for the resources not in the same template without specifying the api version.

```
"[concat('Data Source=tcp:', reference(concat('Microsoft.Sql/servers/', parameters('sqlserverName')), '2014-04-01-preview').fullyQualifiedDomainName, ',1433;Initial Catalog=Admin', ';User Id=', parameters('sqlAdministratorLogin'), '@', reference(concat('Microsoft.Sql/servers/', parameters('sqlserverName')), '2014-04-01-preview').fullyQualifiedDomainName, ';Password=', parameters('sqlAdministratorLoginPassword'), ';')]",
```

you can use reference function without the api version if the resource is in the same template

Comment: my plan was to create a 'shared' template (the first one) that will define everything that will be used by other nested templates (sql server , service bus etc). But I guess it they can be defined in the parent template instead

Comment: you don't need to create nested templates (why complicate things?) unless you **need to workaround ARM Templates limitations**.

Comment: I have quite a lot of resources to create and so I was splitting them up into separate templates by logical area.

Comment: I tried adding the dependency to the parent template a you suggested but I still get the error. I've updated my question to show the parent template, is there anything wrong with it?

Comment: you need to remove the `dependsOn` from the nested template, just like I said

Comment: Sorry, I had removed that from my code but hadn't updated the question to reflect that. Still getting the same error. I assume it's the name of the database resource that it's failing on as that has the server name in

Comment: did you update the actual template in the storage account or where ever you are storing it. i'm pretty sure that's why it errors out. can you provide the links to the nested templates? @ADringer

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/147561/discussion-between-adringer-and-4c74356b41).

Comment: Thanks a lot for debugging my template, got it working!

Comment: How do you define dependencies to a nested template? Lets say I have a Function App that I define in ARM in the main template, and this Function App needs VNET integration. The VNET itself is defined in the nested template

Comment: you cant, you can depend on the template only (a resource in the main template, can depend on the nested template deployment)